# Check authorization token in ReactJS against a Rest API

Tags: reactjs, json, authentication

I am currently trying to design a new web-application for a rest-api service I have running. In basic I am trying to realize the login/logoff system. For authorization-management the API provides three endpoints:

- `/login`, which takes username and password via a `POST` request and returns a token embedded in a json answer. This token is not a JWT, but its some arbitrary unique string. It is valid for X hours and everytime it used it is reset to be X hours valid again. The validity is check on the server in each request.
- `/logout`, which makes the token invalid on the server.
- `/validate`, which takes a token as json in POST request and checks if it is valid. If not it returns a 401.

Now I realized a login procedure following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications . The application finally should used the `react-router` to provide the different pages. My problem is not how to integrate the validation of the token on each page change and if a 401 is returned, switch to the login page again.

PS: The server is written in C++ and accesses a custom database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested By You That You Want To Integrate Validation, So You Need To Create A Component Over The Current Route Component.

It would serve as the private Route and as soon as you get a 401 Response From Your Server You Would Redirect To The Login Page By Updating the Token as empty depenedending upon the storage you are using i.e. session storage or localstorage.

This way whenever your token expires the next request responds with 401 and you are logged out.

Further I am Linking An Example Gist For Creating Private Routes And Logging Out
`https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d`

Comment: In general that sounds good. A small questuion what is in your `../services/auth` module ? Since I am normally a C/C++/Fortran programmer, it is a bit hard for me to think in the JavaScript world. And I am still not aware of all the features that are available.

Comment: yes please ask any further doubts you have

Comment: that file contains functions for login signup basically the api request you will make those are extracted into a file and imported into the context of the react application so that you can check the authentication and logout the user from any component of your react app . i am linking one more link here the route is made without using context https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e

Comment: as synchronous or asynchronous calls?

Comment: these are synchronous calls as you can not let any other thing run under the private component till the time you know that the user has the permission you can further make more over these private routes and set them restricted for specific users

Comment: I don't get it working due to the asynchronous behaviour of the `fetch` call and the missing proper "wait" statement in Javascript. Do you have an example of your `services/auth` file on the GIST?